# Svg display wrong after remove whitespace

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I want to create a font from SVG such that each letter is positioned next to the other without any whitespace. However, to achieve this, I need to remove the empty space within the SVG in width while keeping the position of the letters the same.
Original svg:
[image]

I have tried to remove whitespace through the following code:

```js
const divElement = document.getElementById('svg1');
const svgElements = divElement.getElementsByTagName('svg');
console.log(svgElements);
for (var i = 0; i < svgElements.length; i++) {
    var svg = svgElements[i];
    var bbox = svg.getBBox();
    var originalSvg = new DOMParser().parseFromString(svg.outerHTML, "image/svg+xml").querySelector("svg");

    var originalBBox = originalSvg.getBBox();
    var viewBox = [bbox.x, bbox.y, bbox.width, bbox.height].join(" ");
    var width = bbox.width;
    var heightSvg = svg.getAttribute("height");

    svg.setAttribute("viewBox", viewBox);
    svg.setAttribute("width", width);
    svg.setAttribute("height", heightSvg);
    svg.style.overflow = "visible";
}
```

[image]

However, letter "O" display incorrectly, as they do not have the right padding bottom as in the original SVG.

When I use the following code to remove whitespace without changing bbox Y:

```js
const divElement = document.getElementById('svg2');
const svgElements = divElement.getElementsByTagName('svg');
for (var i = 0; i < svgElements.length; i++) {
    var svg = svgElements[i];
    var bbox = svg.getBBox();
    var originalSvg = new DOMParser().parseFromString(svg.outerHTML, "image/svg+xml").querySelector("svg");
    
    var originalBBox = originalSvg.getBBox();
    var viewBox = [bbox.x, originalBBox.y, bbox.width, bbox.height].join(" ");
    var width = bbox.width;
    var heightSvg = svg.getAttribute("height");

    svg.setAttribute("viewBox", viewBox);
    svg.setAttribute("width", width);
    svg.setAttribute("height", heightSvg);
    svg.style.overflow = "visible";
}
```

[image]
The letter "Ь" display incorrectly, as they have the wrong padding bottom, but the letter "O" displays correctly.

I want to output SVG individually as a font.

All code can be found here: https://codepen.io/tozcadaa-the-decoder/pen/GRwZZqv?editors=1010